# PHP Chilkat imap component memory leaking

Tags: php, ubuntu, imap, chilkat

Given:

1. ubuntu 18.04
2. PHP 7.2.2 (cli) (built: May 12 2019 14:29:04) ( ZTS )
3. Chilkat component 9.5.0.78

Session log is disabled.

Script running permanently, connection is via ssh and keep opened.

The following function called periodically:

```
protected function fetchSingle(int $uid)
{
    $e = $this->imap->fetchSingleAsMime($uid, true);
}
```

It is just to demonstrate, that RES and %MEM on linux top keep increasing:

[image]

And very important moment:

after fetching several big emails if there is executed then next code:

```
$this->imap = null;
unset($this->imap);
sleep(324);
```

Then RES and %MEM go down to initial values!

But without

```
$this->imap = null;
unset($this->imap);
```

RES and %MEM stay on high values!

Logically I may predict that problem inside imap CkImap object...

What can I do ? Unset periodically CkImap object and reconnect is not good solution...

Why is it so ? Maybe chilkat is storing data somewhere in itself ? And I should call some method to clear it ?

Reproducible code:

```
<?php

require "core/Chilkat.php";

$ckGlobal = new CkGlobal();

$ckGlobal->UnlockBundle('XXXX');

$imap = new CkImap();
$imap->put_Utf8(true);
$imap->put_Ssl(true);
$imap->put_Port(993);
$imap->put_PeekMode(true);

$imap->Connect('imap');

$imap->Login('login', 'password');

$imap->SelectMailbox('Inbox');

// UID of last message
preg_match('/UID (\d+)/', $imap->sendRawCommand("FETCH * (UID)"), $result);


$i = 0;
while(true){
    var_dump('FETCHING');
    $mime = $imap->fetchSingleAsMime($result[1], true);
    var_dump('SLEEP');
    sleep(5);
    if(++$i >= 5) {
        var_dump('UNSET');
        $imap = null;
        unset($imap);
        sleep(666);
    }
}
```

With the above code we fetch email each 5 seconds and RAM consumption is increasing unstoppable. But it must not, because we overwrite the $mime variable. And once imap is unset - RAM goes down to first value.

`get_VerboseLogging` - this is false by default. And Peek mode I also tried to set to false. Nothing helped to solve or figure out the problem.

Even after `$imap->Disconnect();` RAM will not be decreased..

Comment: If you can provide a [mcve] that demonstrates this, it might be possible to tell whether it's a bug in your code or whether it is a bug somewhere else. Without that info, it's impossible to tell the right way to proceed.

Comment: just fetch several big emails, I provided the code, that's enough. It will increase RAM continueasly. I will add such full code

Comment: Please read the link: Neither the snippits you provide are okay (not enough to be reproducible) nor the full code (which probably contains irrelevant parts)!

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt, I have added simple code tested by me

Answer (score 0):

When it stays at about the same utilization level, just ignore it and add more RAM ...but when it keeps growing, then you'll have to periodically purge the leakage. With closed source you can only complain at the vendor, who might also have established best practices for using their library.

According to [Chilkat_9_5_0.Imap](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/phpImapRef.html), there is a property `VerboseLogging`

... and also property `PeekMode` might affect the memory utilization.

Comment: You are absolutely right! RAM is increasing permanently. Without vendors help I can only do something like reopen process...

Comment: @Mikael it may also have to do with [RFC 4549 - Synchronization Operations for Disconnected IMAP4 Clients](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4549), which means: the mailbox size. Even with closed source, one can attach a debugger - despite one cannot fix anything.

Comment: the link you gave is just explanation of IMAP protocol. I don't think there maybe something regarding memory leaking problem

Comment: @Mikael I find the memory usage in the screenshot not even extreme (this is far from OOM), and IMAP works differently than POP3, since it rather expects a connection - and it fetches more than just the index. I'd rather wonder about the SSH tunnel instead of IMAPS, since mail-servers most often have a public IP.

Comment: on screenshot it is not extreme, it's just to show what I mean. On live server with 250GB RAM it increases unstoppable.. Ssh is socket connection, it uses buffers.. I really think problem is in chilkat CkImap object

Comment: @Mikael This might be by design - and not caching to local file-system; there is a difference in between online and offline mode, when it comes to IMAP clients. One can also write them rather lightweight, but a fully implemented IMAP client needs some RAM & drive-space. The SSH tunnel just adds one additional component, which might not be required with IMAPS. Fetching some mails can also be easily done without third party code.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize! I have checked this code more carefully and seems RAM increased until specific limit! But still interesting why it is increasing..